# Xcode "Analyze" message confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have inherited an old Objective C project which is not using ARC, and due to third party library uses, can use ARC.

I'm attempting to resolve a number of random crash caused by access un/deallocated memory.

One of my first tasks was to run Xcode's "Analyze" tool and see what issues it discovered.  For the most part, it's been very useful and mostly common sense to resolve the issues.

However, I have a few classes (namely custom `UITableViewCell`s) which are causing me some concerns and I don't know how to resolve the issues

[image: Potential leak of an object]

Actual class

```
#import "userListView.h"

@implementation userListView
@synthesize userCustomCelltextlabel,userCustomDetailtextlabel;
@synthesize unreadIdentifierImg;

-(void)dealloc {
  [userCustomCelltextlabel release];
  [userCustomDetailtextlabel release];
  [unreadIdentifierImg release];
  [super dealloc];
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {

    self.unreadIdentifierImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,1,12,38)];

    self.userCustomCelltextlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,5,150,20)];
    self.userCustomCelltextlabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:13.0f];
    self.userCustomCelltextlabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    self.userCustomDetailtextlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,22,150,15)];
    self.userCustomDetailtextlabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.userCustomDetailtextlabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    self.userCustomDetailtextlabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0];

    self.userCustomDetailtextlabel.numberOfLines=1;
    self.userCustomDetailtextlabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;


    //self.unreadIdentifierImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MessageEntrySendButton.png"];
    //self.unreadIdentifierImg.hidden=YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.unreadIdentifierImg];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.userCustomDetailtextlabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.userCustomCelltextlabel];


  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

And header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface userListView : UITableViewCell

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *userCustomCelltextlabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *userCustomDetailtextlabel;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *unreadIdentifierImg;

@end
```

Expanding on the errors shows...

```
// 2. Method returns an instance of UIImageView with a +1 retain count
self.unreadIdentifierImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,1,12,38)];
// Seems to point to UIImageView init

// 3. Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
self.userCustomCelltextlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,5,150,20)];
// Which seems to point to the UILabel init
```

And repeats for `userCustomDetailtextlabel`.  The issue I have here is `allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path`, which isn't true as it's added to the `contentView`.

Now, obviously, we want to retain the objects as properties for the class and dispose of them only when the object is deallocated, but I can't seem to make heads or tails of the messages.

Should I ignore them?  Is there something else I should be looking into to try and solve them?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it cannot use ARC? ARC and MRC can be combined without problems. That code could use some modern Obj-C. You could use property autosynthesis, removing those `@synthesize` calls. Conversion to ARC would probably only need `retain` to be replaced with `strong`. If you don't want to migrate to ARC, you will really need to understand what `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` do.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, I converted the project previously to use ARC (and was very happy with the result), but the third party library crashed the app at specific points during the execution and I'm not allowed to update the library :P

Comment: That seems like a problem with the migration, not the library... :)

Comment: @Sulthan Given the leave of crap code that this entire project is, I have no doubt, but right now, I just need to get it stable and running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are declared with a retain, so the compiler will generate a setter method that retains the value.

You create the labels with alloc/init what gives you a label with a retain count of +1, after that you assign it to your property using `self.userCustomCelltextlabel` this calls the according setter method which is sending a retain to the label, now it has a retain count of +2.

In dealloc you send release and the label has a retain count of +1 and is leaking.

Add an `autorelease` to your alloc/init or assign it to the ivar directly with  `_userCustomCelltextlabel`.

Comment: Okay, that seems to make sense, I'll apply it and see what I come up with - thanks

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have corrected the warnings and overall makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If this is the first time you've encountered manual memory management in Objective-C – also referred to as "manual retain-release" – and if this project can't be migrated to ARC, then I can only suggest that you take the time to learn about manual memory management. The Memory-Management page in [the Cocoa Core Competencies guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1) and the Practical Memory Management page in [the Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1) are two good places to start.

Unfortunately, manual memory management in its entirety is too big to be a good fit for a Stack Overflow answer, but I'll explain what's happening for one of those objects – on this line:

```
self.unreadIdentifierImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,1,12,38)];
```

---

When you call `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: ... ];` you allocate memory and create a new object. According to the Cocoa *ownership policy* you "own" this object and are responsible for its memory since you called `alloc`. At this point this newly created object has a retain count of 1.

When you assign that object to `self.unreadIdentifierImg` it will retain the object that's assigned to it. This happens because the property is defined as `@property (retain, nonatomic) ...`.  This retains the objects retain count, which means that it's now at 2.

Since the image view is neither retained nor released throughout the rest of that scope, you end up with an image view with a retain count of two (one from when it was created and one from the property that references it).

Later when cell is deallocated and releases the image view (either explicitly calling release or setting the property to `nil`) the retain count of the image view is decremented, which means that it's now at 1 (from when it was created). Since there are no other references to this image view and since it's retain count is not 0, this object has now leaked.

To fix it, you will want to release it once after it's been assigned to the retaining property. Most likely you'll do this by "auto releasing" it, which means that the object will be added to the current autorelease pool – to be released at a later time when the pool is drained:

```
self.unreadIdentifierImg = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,1,12,38)] autorelease];
```

Note that the is an added `autorelease` call at the end of that line.

---

In my experience the static analyzer is pretty much always right when it warns about things like this, so it would be advisable to go through each of these warnings and investigate them thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'm very big on self learning, so I appreciate the links and additional informaiton